# Cut an audio segment of a MP3 file with NAudio

Tags: c#, vb.net, audio, naudio, naudio-framework

I'm using [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) library. I wrote the function below that given a `WaveStream` will cut a segment of its audio, for example, I can use it to cut 30 seconds of a music file as I represented in this graphic:

[image]

```
public static IWaveProvider CutAudio(WaveStream wave, 
                                     TimeSpan startPosition, 
                                     TimeSpan endPosition) {

    ISampleProvider sourceProvider = wave.ToSampleProvider();
    long currentPosition = wave.Position; // Save stream position

    // Take audio from the beginning of file until {startPosition}
    OffsetSampleProvider offset1 = new OffsetSampleProvider(sourceProvider) {
        Take = startPosition
    };

    // Take audio after {endPosition} until the end of file
    OffsetSampleProvider offset2 = new OffsetSampleProvider(sourceProvider) {
        SkipOver = (endPosition - startPosition),
        Take = TimeSpan.Zero
    };

    wave.Position = currentPosition; // Restore stream position
    return (offset1.FollowedBy(offset2)).ToWaveProvider();

}
```

This is an example usage:

```
 string sourceFile = "C:\\File.mp3";
 string outputFile = "C:\\Output.wav"; // It must be a WAVE file

 using (AudioFileReader reader = new AudioFileReader(sourceFile))
 {
     TimeSpan startPosition = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:05.000");
     TimeSpan endPosition = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:10.000");
     IWaveProvider wave = CutAudio(reader, startPosition, endPosition);

     WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputFile, wave);
 }
```

It works for MP3 files by passing a `Mp3FileReader` or an `AudioFileReader` classes as argument to the function, but the problem with this function is it converts MP3 files to WAVE format, so once the cut is applied in the audio I need to save it as a new WAVE file.

I know `NAudio` can parse MP3 samples using the `Mp3FileReader` class, so I would like to do cuts (and other modifications) directly to the MP3 file stream by using `Mp3FileReader.ReadNextFrame()` and writing a new MP3 file, instead of taking the time and disk space to converting to WAVE format and writing a WAVE file.

I seen some examples using the `Mp3FileReader.ReadNextFrame()`, but It's not really clear for me how to adapt it for this functionality to match the exact function I wrote above, with the timings accuracy.

My question is: in C# or VB.NET, how can I adapt the function above to work with MP3 files / `Mp3FileReader` without converting them to WAVE format?

Comment: Are you trying to edit the MP3 in the compressed domain (very hard given it could be VBR and one frame contains multiple samples) or are you trying to re-encode it to an MP3 file using an MP3Writer? Do you hope for frame-level accuracy or sample-level accuracy for your edits?

Comment: @Ian Mercer Thanks for comment. I'm not an expert about MP3 or audio format structures in general... I just would like to cut 'X' amount of samples (the amount would be based and calculated by the TimeSpan arguments), so I imagine this would generate two MP3 file chunks, without re-encoding, so later I can combine those two file streams into one. A direct cut without re-encoding. My MP3 files are CBR. I would like to achieve, if possible, same kind of timing accuracy as in the function I shared.